# Excel - Inserting a pdf picture using a formula

Tags: excel, pdf, import, excel-formula

I want excel to recall a certain PDF document and insert it into the worksheet if certain cells match the allocated PDF info.

I've tried using the object insert but it only gives me an un-editable formula which of course is:

```
=EMBED(" Forms.CommandButton.1")
```

Which does not work.

I then moved on to trying to nest `IF` & `AND` statements, but that doesn't get me very far, seeing that I don't know how, or whether it is possible to add a PDF document into that formula.

I've tried using hyperlinks but it seems that the hyperlinks are set and do not work with `IF` or `AND` statements.

Any suggestions or solutions are welcome.

Thanks!